# Creating a procedural material from an image reference

Tags: materials, shaders, lighting, procedural

I am new to blender so I don't have that much of an experience working with procedural materials yet.
I need to create a material similar to that covering the walls on the reference images
below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I went with this setup of a plastic looking material:

[image]

[image]

Although the color is some-what right the overall feeling to it is not there.
What you guys can recommend in order to improve the look of the material?

Ps: I had to copress my render image becouse it was too big, so there might be some qulity loss.

Comment: I would say that it doesn't seem as reflective as what you've done

Comment: @moonboots the material looks kind of fake for me, but I have no clue why. I'll try to reduce reflectiveness through

Comment: maybe you need a bit of texture, either Image Texture or Noise Texture, to get some color and/or roughness variations? Or some very small bumps?